# Javascript Regex Allow One Decimal

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

javascript code

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

this works well for the numbers. but it adds multiple decimals.i just want it to allow only one decimal. any sort of help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: yes its working perfectly on other pages. but creating issue here.

Comment: What decimal does it add?